# BizTalk 2013 R2: Error in receive pipeline

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Facing an issue after deployment of BizTalk solution on another server.
Error is highlighted below:-

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline:
>   "BTAHL72XPipelines.BTAHL72XReceivePipeline, BTAHL72XPipelines,
>   Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
>   Source: "BTAHL7 2.X Disassembler" Receive Port:
>   "HL7_25_ADT_A02_ReceivePort" URI: "******Some Location*******"
>   Reason: Field not found:
>   'Microsoft.Solutions.BTAHL7.Pipelines.MessageUtils.VersionforAck24'.

PS: I have already installed BizTalk 2013 R2 with HL7 Accelerator R2 two times on server.

Comment: can you say more about your problem. Forexample if it is a custom pipeline you are using and if it was worked on previous server etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier we were using window server 2012.

> In order to fix this issue, we did installation for window server 2012 R2,
>      Sql server 2014, VS 2013 and Framework 4.5.

Thanks all for helping out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearlyunderstand if it is a custom pipeline but if it is then you should copy your custom pipeline component to path

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\Pipeline Components

if you are on development environment and tired of copying dll  then a good way is:
Your dll mus must be deployed in GAC. Then a simpler way to do that is using gacutil.exe to deploy it. By the help of Visual Studio you can achieve this by post build event

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" /i $(TargetPath)

[image]

After that you don't have to copy any dll but in production this may leads you forgetting to copy be careful.

Comment: Thanks for revert Halis, But still no luck

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me a installation issue, I have been running BizTalk 2013 R2 with HL7 Accelerator without any issues. Some suggestions

1. Most likely you have an old version of Microsoft.Solutions.BTAHL7.PipelineCommon.dll (possibly 2010 version). Make sure its version is 3.11.158.0. This assembly can be found in "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk 2013 R2 Accelerator for HL7\Bin" folder.
2. Uninstall HL7 Accelerator and Install it again, make sure you use 2013 R2 iso file

Answer (score 0):

Is the assembly Microsoft.Solutions.BTAHL7.PipelineMessageCore deployed?  Check under All Artifacts->Resources.  Try redeploying it if it's in there.

Also take a look at the schema from that assembly under All Artifacts->Schemas and make sure it has the node.  If it doesn't, you definitely have to redeploy from the original installation version, or at least undo any modifications that hav ebeen made to rename/remove that node.